# Invertibility of certain matrices which are sum of invertible matrices[CSIR-UGC NET]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $det(A)>0$ and $det(B)<0$, where $A,B$ are $n\times n $ matrices. Let $C(t)=tA+(1-t)B\space \forall t\in [0,1]$. Then is $C(t)$  invertible only for finitely many $t \in [0,1]$?

Its easy to see that $C(t)$ is invertible at $0,1$. Also, determinant is a polynomial of degree $n$. But, since $ t $ takes real values, I dont see how only finite values of $t$ would make $C(t)$ invertible. Any hints?

Comment: This can't be true. Possibly a misprint. In fact, $C(t)$ is not invertible only for finitely many $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @i707107 any hints of proof?

Comment: The determinant is zero for only finitely many values, because it is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$.

Comment: Also, $p(t)=\det C(t)$ is a continuous function with $p(0)<0<p(1)$. So, it must be a nonconstant polynomial with at least one zero in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @i707107 thanks, so the intermediate value theorem is the key here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments by i707107, the answer relies upon the fact that the determinant polynomial $p(t)=|C(t)|$ is a continuous function with $p(0)<0<p(1)$ because of the given conditions. Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $t_0\in (0,1)$ such that $p(t_0)=0$. However, being a polynomial, it is zero at only **atmost** $n$ points in the interval $(0,1)$.